# Solve a system of two equations with cubic radicals

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Solve the following system of equations ($x,y \in \Bbb R$):

$$\begin{cases} 
(8x-13)y&=(x+1)\sqrt[3]{3y-2}-7x \\ 
 (y-1)x^2+(8y+7)x&=y^2+12y+(x+1)\sqrt[3]{3y-2}.
\end{cases}$$

I think this system of equations have no solution, but I can't prove it.

Comment: Hint: $(x+1)\sqrt[3]{3y-2}$ seems to appear twice.

Comment: Where did the problem come from?  Is it a model of some system?  Please give some context.

Comment: one solution is $$x=1,y=1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: we have $$(8x-13)y+7x=(y-1)x^2+(8y+7)x-y^2-12$$ from here we get (after simplifying)
$$y(y-1)=x^2(y-1)$$
can you proceed?

Comment: Yes, you're right. How do we solve the system of equations $$\begin{cases} 
(8x-13)x^2&=(x+1)t-7x \\ 
 t^3+2&=3x^2.
\end{cases}$$ (in this case $y=x^2,\ t=\sqrt[3]{3y-2}$)

Answer (score 1):

HINT$$8xy-13y+7x=yx^2-x^2+8xy+7x-y^2-12y=(x+1)\sqrt[3]{3y-2}$$It follows $$(x^2-y)(y-1)=0$$ 
$y=1\Rightarrow x=1$ so $(x,y)=(1,1)$ is a solution.

On the other hand $x=\pm y$ gives the following two equations in $y$

$$\begin{cases} 512y^6+1152y^5+861y^4+209y^3-3y^2+3y+2=0\\512y^6-3840y^5+9603y^4-8011y^3+15y^2-9y+2=0\end{cases}$$

Both equations being irreducible, I rather stop here.

Comment: @ Piquito: I think that in this case $y=x^2$ you should let $t=\sqrt[3]{3y-2}$. So, we have $$\begin{cases}  (8x-13)x^2&=(x+1)t-7x \\   t^3+2&=3x^2. \end{cases}$$.

Comment: I fear that leads to change in the two last equations $y$ by $x^2$. Anyway, you can try your possibility. Regards.

Comment: Ok, but How do you can solve a equation with $\deg f=5$?

Comment: With degree $5$ you try first at all to see if it is reducible. If it is not the case, then either, you see Wolfram (I don't like this way) and  lie in some way about your answer, or honestly you leave the problem,